# Top N values in window frame

Tags: postgresql

I have a table t with 3 fields of interest:
d (date), pid (int), and score (numeric)

I am trying to calculate a 4th field that is an average of each player's top N (3 or 5) scores for the days before the current row.

I tried the following join on a subquery but it is not producing the results I'm looking for:

```
SELECT t.d, t.pid, t.score, sq.highscores 
FROM t, (SELECT *, avg(score) as highscores FROM
   (SELECT *, row_number() OVER w AS rnum
    FROM t AS t2
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY score DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) isq
    WHERE rnum <= 3) sq
WHERE t.d = sq.d AND t.pid = sq.pid
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I'm a hobbyist programmer and this is more complex of a query than I'm used to.

Comment: If you provide some sample values then it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select `*` **and** `avg(score)` in the same (inner) query. I.e. which non-aggregated values should be selected for each average? PostgreSQL won't decide this instead of you.

Becasue you `PARTITION BY pid` in the innermost query, you should use `GROUP BY pid` in the aggregating subquery. That way, you can `SELECT pid, avg(score) as highscores`:

```
SELECT   pid, avg(score) as highscores
FROM     (SELECT *, row_number() OVER w AS rnum
          FROM t AS t2
          WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY score DESC)) isq
WHERE    rnum <= 3
GROUP BY pid
```

*Note*: `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` makes no difference for `row_number()`.

But if the *top N* part is fixed (and N will be few in your real-world use-case too), you can solve this without that much subquery (with the `nth_value()` window function):

```
SELECT d, pid, score,
       (coalesce(nth_value(score, 1) OVER w, 0) +
        coalesce(nth_value(score, 2) OVER w, 0) +
        coalesce(nth_value(score, 3) OVER w, 0)) /
       ((nth_value(score, 1) OVER w IS NOT NULL)::int +
        (nth_value(score, 2) OVER w IS NOT NULL)::int +
        (nth_value(score, 3) OVER w IS NOT NULL)::int) highscores
FROM   t
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY score DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

http://rextester.com/GUUPO5148